# How to use Date - formatted as YYYYMM under a macro in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset where Period is in **`YYYYMM`** format and I created a macro to call that macro as :

```
data _null_;
date=today();
call symputx('month',put(intnx('month',date,-1,'e'),yymmn6.));
call symputx('period1',put(intnx('month',date,-1,'e'),date9.));

data _null_;
    call symputx('period1_fmt',put(input("&period1",date9.),yymmdd10.));

data _null_;
    call symput("yyyymm",   put(input("&period1", anydtdte9.), yymmn6.));
    call symput("period1",put(intnx('month',input("&period1",anydtdte9.),-1,'e'),yymmn6.));
run;
```

Now I wanted to call 201807 which is stored as &Period1  under another macro e.g.

```
%macro Checkdate(Date=);

    Proc sql;
        create table temp1_0 as
            select T1.MERC_ID,
                'CHURNED' as CATEGORY
            from RPT_Response_FC  as t1
                WHERE Period= &Date.
                    GROUP BY    T1.MERC_ID
        ;
    quit;

%mend;

%Checkdate(Date=&Period1);
```

But it's showing error as

> ERROR: Expression using equals (=) has components that are of different data types.

It would be great if anyone could help me in that regards. How could I solve that error.

I converted the `&Period1` to numeric by using `Sysfunc` but still it's showing the same error.

Comment: Just try by giving `&Date.` inside double quotes. Something like **`WHERE Period= "&Date."`**

Comment: What type of variable is PERIOD in the RPT_RESPONSE_FC dataset?  Is it character or numeric? If it is numeric does it use the  YYMMn6. format to make it look like YYYYMM? or is just storing the digits as an integer (ie year*100 + month)?

Answer (score 0):

Expression using equals (=) has components that are of different data types. That means, you have to keep the macro variable call inside double quotes. Like, **`WHERE Period= "&Date."`**

**Code**

```
%macro Checkdate(Date=);

    Proc sql;
        create table temp1_0 as
            select t1.MERC_ID,
                'CHURNED' as CATEGORY
            from RPT_Response_FC  as t1
            WHERE Period= "&Date."
            GROUP BY    T1.MERC_ID;
    quit;

%mend;

%Checkdate(Date=&Period1);
```